fastify disableRequestLogging not working
I am using fastify 4.24.3.I tried to disable incoming request logs those are autogenerated as shown below.
[App] [17:04:51.617] INFO (31284): incoming request
[App]     reqId: "req-1"
[App]     req: {
[App]       "method": "POST",
[App]       "url": "/myapp/v1/test",
[App]       "hostname": "localhost:3000",
[App]       "remoteAddress": "::1",
[App]       "remotePort": 8999
[App]     }

We tried to disable it while creating fastify instance but still showing logs. How to disable these autogenerated logs?
const app = Fastify(
    {
         logger: false,
        disableRequestLogging :true,
    }
);


Setting disableRequestLogging: true should disabled the default incoming requests logs. Can you share additional code of how fastify server is created and configured?

Setting logger: false disable all the logs, so I think there is something in the code that we can't see in the question
